# Applying saliva to mosquito bites

Tags: human-biology, saliva

Is it true that; when you apply your own saliva to a mosquito bite it would stop itching ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There have been many personal experiences documented where people have experienced relief from itching of mosquito bites on the application of their own saliva to the itchy spot ([reference 1](http://www.correntewire.com/mosquito_bite_trick), [reference 2](http://www.qryztufre.com/superstitions/saliva.html)) It helps to reduce the itching because saliva has been proven to speed up tissue repair and has antibacterial properties. It also provides a moisturising effect on the itchy spot ([reference](http://oralpathol.dlearn.kmu.edu.tw/case/Journal%20reading-intern-08-04/Saliva-function-composition-J%20Comtemp%20Dent%20Pract-2008.pdf)). Salt is also known to provide relief to itching ([reference](http://www.livestrong.com/article/291635-salt-grains-on-itching-skin/)) and the slight salt content of saliva helps in that respect too.

Comment: If the skin is broken from scratching, though, it would also be inoculating an open wound with oral bacteria - which can lead to infection.

Comment: @DoctorWhom Most of what I found on the advantages of applying saliva to reduce itching is based on personal experiences and I couldn't find any reliable source or research for the same. I wouldn't depend on it as a sure fire cure for itching as such. Of course, in the case of open wounds there definitely is a risk of infection. Might work as a first stage to reduce itching before scratching your skin off.

Comment: Agreed - I hadn't heard of it before actually, so it's an interesting concept.  I just wanted to mention infection to go along with the saliva, because a lot of people suck on skin-breaking injuries (and to put a plug in for that, the best thing (even more than antibacterial ointment, which has limited utility and isn't often recommended) is washing it IMMEDIATELY with soap and lots of water).   Our mouths are quite full of life - microorganism life ;)